# reverse the order of the entire list for doubly linkedList

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I was reading about queues in java implementation. I want to implement the following task:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList
{
    private Node first; // the first Node in the list
    private Node last; // the last Node in the list  

    private class Node
    {
        private Point p;
        private Node prev; // the previous Node
        private Node next; // the next Node
    }  

    public void reverse()
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

I did like this:

```
public void reverse() { // that reverses the order of the entire list
    if (first == null && last == null) {
         throw new RuntimeException(); 
    }  

    Node current = first;
    while (current!=null) {
        current.next= current.next.prev;
        current.prev=current.prev.next;
        current=current.next;
    }  
}
```

Am I doing right?
thanks

Comment: does what you have work as expected?

Comment: `throw new` ... missing something there.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Create a Test list, call reverse, compare the result ... that should answer your question

Comment: It this a circular list?

Comment: you can also create a temporary list and traverse the original backwards and save the nodes in reverse order and use that as output.

Comment: @Joe but it is still off-topic. "Why isn't this code working?" is as off-topic as posting a homework question. Attach a debugger and find out yourself why your code is faulty. ;-)

Comment: @dave823 I have one more question: look at this code : `public class ArrayQueue { private String [] a; private int N; private int back; private int front; public boolean isEmpty() { return a.length==0; }` Is my isEmpty() method correct? thanks

Comment: AxelH xenteros Blaatz0r

Comment: @Vampire: homework, by itself, is not off-topic. Please use our standard options instead, if the question is lacking an MCVE, there is an off-topic option for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't change the first and last pointer in your code. Why are you throwing an exception if the list is empty?

I guess I would do something like:

```
public void reverse()
{
    Node current = first;
    while (current != null) {
        Node next = current.next;
        current.next = current.prev;
        current.prev = next;
        current = next;
    }
    Node temp = first;
    first = last;
    last = temp;
}
```

Comment: I have one more question: look at this code : public class ArrayQueue { private String [] a; private int N; private int back; private int front; public boolean isEmpty() { return a.length==0; } Is my isEmpty() method correct? thanks

Comment: This should be in an other post, but at first sight, I would rather return N == 0

Comment: I suppose it is, yes

Answer (score 2):

No it is not. `current.next = current.next.prev` is like `current.next = current` and `current.prev = current.prev.next` is like `current.prev = current`. Please attach a debugger and follow your code to find the errors and the right solution. We won't do your homework here. ;-)